# android:previewImage does not always work

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

i use

```
 <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="40dp"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:previewImage="@drawable/wgprevmini"
android:updatePeriodMillis="21600000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_speriod"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
android:configure="com.chris.mydays.setwidgetuser"
/>
```

the preview image shows on SOME Device, but not on all.

For example
- Samsung Galaxy S5 (Android 5.0) 
  it shows the preview just fine

- Moto G (android 5.0.2)
  it shows the Android Robot Icon ?
- Nexus One (android 2.3.6)
  it shows the Application icon
- Moto X (android 5.0.2)
  it shows the Application icon

Is there any solution i can make sure it shows the Preview Image always
(do i need a special image format .. not its simple .png)

thx
chris

Comment: AFAIK, that is up to the home screen implementation.

Comment: what do u mean exactly.. the public class UpdateWidgets extends Service {
 or  public class WordWidget_big extends AppWidgetProvider {
 ???

Comment: "what do u mean exactly" -- I mean that there are ~1.5 billion Android devices, spanning thousands of device models, running hundreds (if not thousands) of different home screen implementations. Some users use the home screen that shipped with their device; others install third-party home screen implementations from the Play Store or elsewhere. It is the home screen that implements the app widget picker, and so it is the developers of the home screen that choose *how* to design that picker. Some may use the preview image, but they are not forced to at gunpoint.

Comment: ok.. i understand that there are many different devices and how u implement the widget. but one thing should be standart that u can define since ..not sure api 13 or so... android:previewImage=
to show not just the Icon in the widget picker list of the device, instead show a preview how the widget will look like.
Its a official Feature from Android api, right?
So when I use this official android:previewImage=
What could i do wrong that it show the preview not on all devices (later api 13)??

Comment: "Its a official Feature from Android api, right?" -- sure, but developers do not have to use every feature. There is no requirement that developers of home screens *have* to use the preview image. Heck, home screens do not have to support app widgets at all. They do not have to support resizeable app widgets, or various other features of app widgets. Short of using guns or other weapons, you have no means of forcing the world's home screen developers to do what you demand and always use the preview image. And note that using weapons this way may be illegal in some jurisdictions.

Comment: :) without loosing in philosophy.. its just about a standard option that should work on standard devices.
following worked:
Settings / Apps / Google App / Manage Space / CLEAR ALL DATA 
and voila, the preview appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but when the Preview Image does not show up, restarting device always solve my problem. You may want to try it